# Mac OS Equivalent file path for Windows file path

Tags: linux, macos, window, filepath

I am setting up a Java project which uses JBoss which is customized for our project. In one of the properties file under JBoss configuration it has absolute path for various files such as following:

```
com.mycompany.abc.host.certificate=file:///c:/somedir/jboss/myproject/configuration/security/xxx/test.crt
```

I am setting up my dev environment on MacBook having macOS Sierra. What would be the equivalent path on macOS for the corresponding Windows path, say for this file: `/Users/john/jboss/myproject/configuration/security/xxx/test.crt`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Finder, do a right-click on the file of which you need the path. Then press the Option key (`alt`) to open the context menu. Select `Copy "name_of_file" as path`. Then you have the path, for example

```
/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist
```

To get the file URI, add `file://`, like so

```
file:///Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist
```

Comment: Just tried opening with Spotlight search and it worked, thank you. So in case of mac (or linux) prefix it with `file://` (2 slashes) only whereas on Windows we have to prefix with `file:///` (3 slashes). Just wondering why it's different in Windows and Mac?

Comment: @Learner unix (including macOS) and Linux systems organize their filesystems *very* differently from how Windows does. Most obviously, drive letters (like "c:") are a DOS/Windows thing; you just won't find them on other OSes. Then there's the directory hierarchy and naming conventions: there it's just a matter of different people making different decisions. In order for them to match, either one would've had to copy the other (like Linux copied unix), or they'd have had to get together and agree on something; neither happened.

Comment: It is three slashes in total after the `file:` on all OSes. The complete path on macOS starts with a slash (instead of the drive letter).

Comment: Well, but you mentioned `file:///Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist` which is 2 slashes after `file:` and then file path `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleFileServer.plist`

Comment: Yes :) Two slashes from `file:` + one slash from path = three slashes, that's what I meant. But it also works with four slashes on macOS, at least if you try it with Safari. You can find more information on Wikipedia, `file URI scheme`.